# Creating MongoDB index for all items in array

Tags: mongodb

I have some documents in my mongodb database with the following structure, I want to know how to create an index for `document.data.0.data[0-9999].val1`?

My problem is where I type [0-9999] I don't know how many elements will be inside this data array, but I want that all the elements inside this array have an index on the `val1` key.

Any tips?

```js
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("55c455c2fc07853b78c4b6b9"),     
  "data": {
    "0": {
      "data": [
      {
        val1: "abc",
        val2: "def"
      },
      {
        val1: "abc",
        val2: "def"
      }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't include the array index values in the index, so it would just be:

```js
db.mycoll.ensureIndex({'data.0.data.val1': 1})
```

This is termed a [multikey](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-multikey/) index in MongoDB.

Comment: I will try. It will know that it must create the index for all the elements?